# Confused about (fmap length Just) [1,1,1,1] vs. fmap length $ Just [1,1,1,1]

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

I understand that the parens force a different order of operations, but I don't quite understand the first result:

```
>> (fmap length Just) [1, 2, 3]
1
```

Whereas the following makes perfect sense - we are lifting the length function over the Just structure, so we should get "Just [length of list]":

```
>> fmap length $ Just [1, 2, 3]
Just 3
```

What's going on in the first case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the first case, you are getting the function instance of `Functor`, for which `fmap = (.)`, so:

```
fmap length Just [1,2,3]
=
(length . Just) [1,2,3]
=
length (Just [1,2,3])
```

The `Foldable` instance for `Maybe` says that `Nothing`s have a length of `0` and `Just`s have a length of `1` -- which is quite sensible if you think of `Maybe a` as a bit like a collection of `a`s that has at most one `a` in it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. As a noob, how would I have known that the function instance of Functor defines fmap as (.) ? Doing ":i Functor" gives a subtle hint - instance Functor ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
, but that's not really enough.

Comment: @AgentLiquid The [documentation for `Functor`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Functor) includes a list of instances; click "Source" next to the `->` instance in that list.

Comment: @AgentLiquid If `fmap length Just` type checks, this means that `Just` is seen as a value in some functor so `Just :: f a` for some functor `f` and type `a`. Since `Just` is a function, the functor must be `(->) b` for some `b`, and `a` must be `Maybe b`.

Answer (score 0):

---

TL;DR

1. `fmap` can only be applied to two arguments, so first let's focus mostly on `fmap length Just`
2. The `fmap` instance on function is `(.)` *i.e a function composition*, so the expression basically is `(length . Just) [1,2,3]`
3. The above expression is equivalent to `length (Just [1,2,3])`
4. Note that we are applying `length` to a `Maybe` value, which depends on the `Foldable` instance of Maybe. `Foldable` is a typeclass on type constructors, not types (just like `Functor`), so instances don't have different behaviour according to the type of the argument that type constructor take (i.e the `a` in `Maybe a`). The the list `[1, 2, 3]` is just a distraction since lenght can only consult the outermost layerm so the expression is same as `length (Just ())`.
5. A `Maybe` value can only ever contain 0 or 1 values, and `Just` contains 1. So the answer is `1`.

---

Adding to what Daniel said, I would like to explain a little bit in detail as to how we come across this.

The given expression is `fmap length Just [1,2,3]` which can be further written as `((fmap length) Just) [1,2,3]`

Let us see the type definition of all the three functions that we have

```hs
> :t fmap
 fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

> :t length
 length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int

> :t Just
 Just :: a -> Maybe a
```

Now let's substitute the type into `fmap` and see what we get.

```hs
fmap :: (a    ->  b) ->  f a      -> f b
         t a     Int ->  f (t a)  -> f Int
```

Confirming this with ghci

```hs
> :t fmap length
fmap length :: (Functor f, Foldable t) => f (t a) -> f Int
```

It is safe to say that `Functions` are also `Functors` (*More on this later*).

That means we can say that  `f` above is  `-> a` and `(t a)` is `Maybe a` this is okay, because `Maybe` has a foldable instance define. i.e
 `f (t a)` can be written as  `(-> a) (Maybe a)`  which can be written as   `a -> Maybe a` which is the type of `Just`.

Similiary `f Int` can be written as   `(-> a) Int` which is similar to  `a -> Int`

Hence the type definition for `fmap lenght Just` is

```hs
> :t fmap length Just
fmap length Just :: a -> Int
```

But that did not exactly clear my confusion,  Now I know that we get an `Int` with this, but why?? Something is worrying me hear. Lookin at the types above, The only way this would have been possible was if somehow the value from Just got fed into the length.

Okieee! Feeding data into another function reminds me of soemthing. Ahahh! It's something like `Function composition`, I mean if we have something like:

```hs
fmap length Just [1,2,3] == (length . Just) [1,2,3] == (length (Just [1,2,3])
```

That might explain this. But why are we composing the functions here. Something's not fitting the bill here.

It looks as if fmap for two functions is equivalent to the composition of them. Is that even possible?

---

Let's go-ahead and clear up this doubt. There are two questions we need to ask ourselves:

1. Can Function be an instance of Functor?
2. If functions are an instance of Functor what is their fmap implementation?

---

1. Can Function be an instance of Functor?

A little digging later, I found that yes - Function can be an instance of functor. Any function can be written as  `a -> b`, which can be further written as   `(->) a b`,  because `->` is nothing but a type constructor which takes in two arguments.

Now we know that `Functors` can accepts types which have the kind  `* -> *`, but `(->)`  has a kind of `* -> * -> *` which we cannot use, but.. What about  `(->) a` it has a kind of  `* -> *`, we can use this to make an instance of Functor.

---

2. If functions are an instance of Functor what is their fmap implementation?

Now that we know that functions can be an instance of Functor, it's time for their implementation. Digging [into the source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-969), I indeed found an functor instance for `(->)`

```hs
instance  Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

Let's see how we came to that implementation:

The type of `fmap` is:

```
fmap :: (a  ->  b) ->  f a -> f b
```

Substituting `(->) a` for `f` since, functions can also be a functor:

```hs
fmap :: (a  ->  b) ->  f a          -> f b
                       ( (->) r a)  -> f ( (->) r b)
```

which can  be simplified as:

```hs
fmap :: (a  ->  b) ->  f a        -> f b
                      ( r -> a)  -> ( r -> b)
```

So the final type definiton of fmap with a function as functor is:

```hs
fmap :: (a  ->  b) -> ( r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

Ahah! If we look closely, what we see is that , it looks exactly like the type of   `function composition (.)` , where the output from `r -> a` is fed as the input to the first argument `a -> b` which gives us the results `(r -> b)`

That mean, we can safely say that

```hs
instance  Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

---

Thus this proves the point, that when we have fmap over the function as a functor, the instance of fmap is function composition.

Looking back at our question:

```hs
((fmap length) Just) [1,2,3]
```

This can be seen as:

```hs
fmap length Just [1,2,3] == (length . Just) [1,2,3] == (length (Just [1,2,3])
```

The answer of:

```hs
> (length (Just [1,2,3]) == 1
```

A Maybe can ever contain two values `0` and `1`, and since `Just` contains something, we get `Just a` as `1`